# Microsoft Cognitive Services Compability

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use http://Cognitive.Services

In the documentation it says that it supports macOS 10.12 but when I tried to run it in my .NET project it says

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dylib' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable:
> dlopen(/Users/jonataswalker/my_path/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dylib.dylib, 1): Symbol not found: _ZNKSt3_115basic_stringbufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE3strEv
> Referenced from: /Users/jonataswalker/my_path/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dylib.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 12.0

I'm using Mac 11.7. Can somebody help?

I'm trying to use a speech to text azure tool